# Try to implement APA style heading and sub heading but it gives error

Tags: sectioning

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{Thesis} % Paper size, default font size and one-sided paper
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\renewcommand\raggedchapter{\centering}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=.25\baselineskip,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{chapter}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  beforeskip=3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,
  afterskip=1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp
]{section}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  afterskip=-1em,
  indent=2em
]{subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}

\renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat}[4]{%
  \hskip #2#3#4.%
}


\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
% for better rules in the table
% prints author names as small caps
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable}            
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,caption}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered version of "X" type
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
%\usepackage{subcaption} %incompatible with subfig
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib} % Use the natbib reference package - read up on this to edit the reference style; if you want text (e.g. Smith et al., 2012) for the in-text references (instead of numbers), remove 'numbers' v

\hypersetup{urlcolor=black, colorlinks=true} % Colors hyperlinks in blue - change to black if annoyingv`    
\title{\ttitle} % Defines the thesis title - don't touch this
```

BTW: The class `Thesis` comes from [this github using class `ecsthesis.cls`](https://github.com/owst/thesis/blob/master/ecsthesis.cls)

Comment: There is the class https://ctan.org/pkg/apa6 that should give you documents following APA rules as much as possible, so there might not be a need to reinvent the wheel. Please note that every second document class in the TeX world seems to call itself `Thesis`, so it would help us if you could tell us where you got your `Thesis.cls` from (with a link). I should also note that it would help greatly if you could tell us which error you get and if you could turn the preamble code into a full example document, i.e. code with `\begin{document}...\end{document}` that reproduces the issue ...

Comment: ... see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: \sectioncatchphraseformat undefined. \renewcommand{\sectioncatchphraseformat} getting this error

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help you much here, but if you can add those relevant pieces of information to the question by editing it and turn the code into a proper example document maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you are mixing two things:

1. Your used class `ecsthesis.cls` is based on the class `book.cls` which you can see in the line

   ```
   \def\baseclass{book}
   ```

   inside the class.
2. Your used command `\RedeclareSectionCommand[` is not defined in class `book.cls`, it is defined in KOMA-Script class `scrbook.cls`. Same for the command `\raggedchapter` you tried to redefine ...

That both points are the reason you get the error messages

> ```
> ! LaTeX Error: Command \raggedchapter undefined.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>
> l.18 \renewcommand\raggedchapter
>                                 {\centering}
> Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
> If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> l.20 \RedeclareSectionCommand
>                              [
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

The class `ecsthesis` is very old, I would name it outdated, and you should avoid to use it (or do have to use it, because your prof told you?)

Class `scrbook` did a lot of new definitions I'm sure you will hardly get `scrbook` work inside your class `ecsthesis`.

It seems you need an apa style for your document, then why not use the class `apa6.cls` written for this purpose (that was already mentioned in a comment by @moewe).

## Conclusion:

Use another class instead your outdated `ecsthesis.cls` to get the result you need. If you want to use command `\RedeclareSectionCommand[` try to use class `scrbook` instead. If you need the apa style try class `apa6.cls` (see ctan for both).